# Optimization over two sets of vectors

Tags: optimization, algorithms, numerical-optimization

I have two sets of variables vectors $\{{\bf x}_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{{\bf y}_{ij}\}_{(i,j) \in A}$ where $A = \{ (i,j) \text{ such that } i \in \{1,\dots,N\} \text{ and } j \in \{1,\dots,M\} \}$.

I'm looking for an iterative algorithm that solves the following optimization problem
$$ \underset{\{{\bf x}_i\}_{i=1}^N, \{{\bf y}_{ij}\}_{(i,j) \in A}}{\min} \sum_{i=1}^N f_i\left({\bf x}_i, \sum_{j=1}^M {\bf y}_{ij}\right)$$
where the functions $f_i(\cdot)$ are differentiable.

To make myself clearer, let $N=2$ and $M=2$, then my optimization problem writes
$$ \underset{{\bf x}_1, {\bf x}_2, {\bf y}_{11}, {\bf y}_{12}, {\bf y}_{21}, {\bf y}_{22}}{\min} f_1({\bf x}_1, {\bf y}_{11} + {\bf y}_{12}) + f_2({\bf x}_2, {\bf y}_{21} + {\bf y}_{22}) $$

Comment: If the $\mathbf x_i, \mathbf y_{ij}$ are two given sets of vectors, then what does it mean to minimize the expression over them? As you know these values, there is only one value of $ \sum_{i=1}^N f_i({\bf x}_i, \sum_{j=1}^M {\bf y}_{ij})$ to calculate. The result of that sole calculation is both the minimum and the maximum. The way you've worded this is confusing.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I mean the vectors are decision variables in my optimization problem.

Comment: Jargon does not clarify the situation. What is varying here in taking the minimum, and what is the domain of that variation?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I gave an example in the edited post. Not sure if this make things clearer.

Comment: Can't you just differentiate the objective function (the sum of all functions $f_i$) with respect to each design variable? Then you can use any gradient-based optimization method.

Comment: @DanielCunha: I'm not familiar much with optimization. I may try to do that for the example I gave, but for the general form I need help if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that you can just differentiate the objective function and use any gradient-based method to optimize it.

---

Let's define the dependent variable:

$$z_i(y_{i1},...,y_{iM})=\sum_{j=1}^{M} y_{ij}$$

Then, your objective function is given by:

$$h(x_1,x_2,...,x_N,z_1,z_2,...,z_N) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} f_i(x_i,z_i)$$

Its derivatives are given by:

$$\boxed{\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}}$$

$$\boxed{\frac{\partial h}{\partial y_{ij}} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_i}\,\frac{\partial z_i}{\partial y_{ij}} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_i}}$$

---

After computing all derivatives, you can use any gradient-based method, for example, a simple [gradient descent algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)

I consists in defining a step value $\alpha$, then updating each variable as:

$$x_i^{(k+1)} = x_i^{(k)} - \alpha \cdot \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}\!\left(x_i^{(k)},z_i^{(k)}\right)$$

$$y_{ij}^{(k+1)} = y_{ij}^{(k)} - \alpha \cdot \frac{\partial h}{\partial y_{ij}}\!\left(x_i^{(k)},z_i^{(k)}\right)$$

---

If the value of the objective function increases after a step, you should use smaller values for $\alpha$. If there are no constraints for the optimization problem, you may verify if the minimal value has been achieved by checking the value of each derivative (all of them must be zero at the optimal point).

It should be noted that, if there are no additional constraints to the problem, if a minimum exists, then there will be an infinite number of solutions, since any set of $y_{ij}$ with equivalent $\sum_{j=1}^{M} y_{ij}$ results in the same value for the objective function.

Comment: In the update of the gradient descent, the partial derivative in the first equation is evaluated at $x_i^{(k)}$ and $y_{ij}^{(k)}$, and in the second equation, is it also at $x_i^{(k)}$ and $y_{ij}^{(k)}$ or at $x_i^{(k+1)}$ and $y_{ij}^{(k)}$? Also, I assume I can take two different step values $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, right?

Comment: The derivative is evaluated at the current point ($x_i^{(k)}$ and $z_i^{(k)}$). In the vanilla gradient descent algorithm, you should use a single $\alpha$ (the same for all variables), otherwise you would be altering the descent direction.

Comment: Also, if you can easily compute the objective function, that is, if it is not expensive to compute it some dozens of times, you can obtain optimal values for $\alpha$ in each iteration, by performing a binary search (for example): test your function for a grid of step values $[0.0, 10^{-10}, 10^{-9}, 10^{-8}, ...]$; then, identify when the function stops decreasing; lastly, perform the binary search for fine tuning.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm